# Pinax or pure Django for db driven web site

Tags: django, pinax

I'm about to develop a web site that works closely with database attributes.
It needs to fetch required data from the db based on search criteria and to display them as table.

I was studying django and feel that I'm ready to start the development process.

Now, I need to decide rather I choose to go with Pinax or just pure Django with apps that suit my needs.

i do want some social functionality like sending notifications to friends and maybe later a forum on site.

What do you think? should i go with pure Django or should i give Pinax a try?

Answer (score 0):

Pinax wont run without django so you need to use django either way. If you want to create sitw with social networking feature pinax is a good option. If you just need user management, django has it built in.

Comment: Regarding to web design, I have no exprience with web design.
Does Pinax bundled with templates and some css I could reuse?

Comment: Last time I checked it did not. May have changed now, download and check. It seems there are some themes here. https://code.google.com/p/pinax-themes/

Comment: I came across these templates.
Do you any tool for web design/css?

Comment: I use aptana studio for all web design tasks.